# Emit Particles from Centre of Face Uniformly

Tags: particles

[image: Particles emitting from a vertex on the side]

I'm looking to have particles emit uniformly from the middle of this face. However, even with *Faces* selected under *Emit From* (under *Source* tab), they still emit from the vertices (and they switch vertices over time). When I switch over to *Grid* under *Distribution*, they don't emit anymore and stay stuck to the face (though they are centered).

*Random* is also unchecked and *Particles/Face* is set to 1

Answer (score 1):

just make one vertex with these settings: (you can parent the vertex to your object/face, rotation of that vertex is important for particle direction)

[image]

[image]

then you get:

[image]